# Is it possible to run git-fast-export remotely

Tags: git

It is possible to run something like:

```
$ ssh -x git@github.com "git-receive-pack 'schacon/simplegit-progit.git'"
```

Is it possible to run a "remote fast-export" somehow against a git server?

Comment: "a git server"? or specifically github?

Comment: github would be great, yes. I wonder if other kind of git server can (I mean, implementing native git:// protocol)

Comment: Any server running `git-daemon` implements `git://` - and GitHub does support `git://` (but only for read-only connections)

Comment: @Amber: well, they do allow to push too, so I guess also writable connections. Anyway, the question is: is it possible to create a fast-export without having to clone the repo first? That would be great.

Comment: @pablo GitHub only supports read via `git://` - writes are required to use `ssh://` or `https://`.

Comment: And no, GitHub doesn't support `fast-export` directly from their servers.

Comment: @Amber: right! Ouch! I started my question writing ssh, so yes, that's what I meant :) I wanted to know it it is possible to directly run fast-export/import remotely and if not, is there a good alternative? (I'm afraid just replicating locally first, right?)

Comment: Ok, then I'll be writing directly towards the protocol (ouch!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think generally the answer is no. This is prevented by `git-shell` which is the out-of-box interface to git commands through things like SSH, and is what gitorious uses for SSH access.  From the man page:

> Currently, only four commands are permitted to be called,
>   `git-receive-pack` `git-upload-pack` and `git-upload-archive` with a single
>   required argument, or `cvs server` (to invoke `git-cvsserver`).

Other tools like [gerrit](http://gerrit.googlecode.com/svn/documentation/2.2.1/cmd-index.html) and github use different interfaces to git, and have different commands, but neither supports fast-export.

If you have ssh shell access on the git server, you could use something like:

```
$ ssh user@githost "cd ~/gitrepo && git fast-export master" >output
```